# Return list of lists containing all key paths to n-level nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'd like to create a function that returns, from the below nested dictionary, a list of lists where each list within the larger list is an ordered key path from the nested dictionary.

This dictionary is a fake Twitter user object.

```py
{'username': 'fakeusername',
 'location': 'Chicago, IL',
 'description': 'fakedescription',
 'name': 'fakename',
 'url': '',
 'created_at': '2018-01-06T16:02:07.000Z',
 'verified': False,
 'profile_image_url': 'notreal',
 'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 43,
     'end': 56,
     'tag': 'blahblahblah'},
    {'start': 59, 'end': 65, 'tag': 'blahblah'},
    {'start': 125, 'end': 138, 'tag': 'blah'}]}},
 'protected': False,
 'id': '000000000000',
 'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 31779,
  'following_count': 31116,
  'tweet_count': 214997,
  'listed_count': 7},
 'pinned_tweet_id': None}
```

The output should look like this:

```py
[
["username"],
["location"],
["description"],
["name"],
["url"],
["created_at"],
["verified"],
["profile_image_url"],
["entities", "description","hashtags"],
["entities", "description","hashtags"],
["protected"],
["id"],
["public_metrics","followers_count"],
["public_metrics","following_count"],
["public_metrics","tweet_count"],
["public_metrics","listed_count"],
["pinned_tweet_id"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
data = {'username': 'fakeusername', 'location': 'Chicago, IL', 'description': 'fakedescription', 'name': 'fakename', 'url': '', 'created_at': '2018-01-06T16:02:07.000Z', 'verified': False, 'profile_image_url': 'notreal', 'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 43, 'end': 56, 'tag': 'blahblahblah'}, {'start': 59, 'end': 65, 'tag': 'blahblah'}, {'start': 125, 'end': 138, 'tag': 'blah'}]}}, 'protected': False, 'id': '000000000000', 'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 31779, 'following_count': 31116, 'tweet_count': 214997, 'listed_count': 7}, 'pinned_tweet_id': None}
def get_paths(d, p = []):
   if not isinstance(d, dict):
      yield p
   else:
      yield from [j for a, b in d.items() for j in get_paths(b, p+[a])]

print(list(get_paths(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['username'], ['location'], ['description'], ['name'], ['url'], ['created_at'], ['verified'], ['profile_image_url'], ['entities', 'description', 'hashtags'], ['protected'], ['id'], ['public_metrics', 'followers_count'], ['public_metrics', 'following_count'], ['public_metrics', 'tweet_count'], ['public_metrics', 'listed_count'], ['pinned_tweet_id']]
```